# Get enabled add-on features values from an existing org to use them in Salesforce DX org definition file

Tags: api, metadata, org, salesforcedx

In the [Salesforce DX Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/), there is a list of [Supported Features and Preferences](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm?search_text=supported%20features) that can be activated in Scratch Orgs through the [Scratch Org Definition file](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file.htm?search_text=supported%20features).

I can see the description of the Settings in the [Metadata API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_settings.htm), as well as a way to retrieve these for an existing org.

However, I don't know how to get the values defined for the Features for a specific org. Is there a way to get them using an API, to know what should be set in my definition file to match a specific org ?

The features listed in the DX doc is the following one:

```
Supported Features
You can enable these add-on features in a scratch org:

 - API 
 - AuthorApex 
 - Communities 
 - ContractApprovals 
 - CustomerSelfService 
 - CustomApps 
 - CustomTabs 
 - ForceComPlatform 
 - MultiCurrency 
 - PersonAccounts 
 - SalesWave 
 - SControls 
 - ServiceCloud
 - ServiceWave 
 - Sites
```

Comment: This is one of the first questions I have now as we join the SalesForce community and begin setting up our development environment. I know our lead power-user is going to want to turn on a bunch of features in an org (maybe I should have her start in a scratch org).  So, if I cannot cull that data into a definition file with a CLI command, can I instead pull that into a default package that we establish as a base install for any future development scratch orgs we create?  (we are a greenfield company starting with 2GP development)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things coming back from the Tooling API since the beta launch of SalesforceDX.

[image]

Many of them have the [0HE keyprefix](http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/09/obscure-salesforce-object-key-prefixes.html#0HE) of a SettingsTemplate.

Of particular interest is OrganizationSettingsDetail. I'd provide a link to the documentation for it, but I can't currently find it. It does however contain a number of the settings that can *shape* an org.

[image]

It's also all through the source code from the sfdx command line around orgPrefRegistry.js and scratchOrgApi.js.

[image]